# __str__() method in django not callable

Tags: python, django, model

I wrote the following code in my model in Django. When I try to use the `__str__()` method, I get an error that the method isn't callable. Is there something I am missing?

```
from django.db import models
from organizer.models import Startup, Tag

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    slug = models.SlugField(
    max_length=63,
    help_text='A label for URL config',
    unique_for_month='pub_date')
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField('date published',
    auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
    Tag, related_name='blog_posts')
    startups = models.ManyToManyField(
    Startup, related_name='blog_posts')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} on {}" (self.title, self.pub_date.strftime('%Y-%m_%d'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'blog post'
        ordering = ['-pub_date', 'title']
        get_latest_by = 'pub_date'
```

Comment: I am using django.blog_posts.all() to call the __str__ method and getting "'str' object is not callable"

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't telling you that your `__str__` method is uncallable, it is telling you that the string `"{} on {}"` is not callable.

Python is trying to call the string because your attempt at string formatting is incorrect. You could use either of the following:

```
"{} on {}".format(self.title, self.pub_date.strftime('%Y-%m_%d'))


"%s on %s" % (self.title, self.pub_date.strftime('%Y-%m_%d'))
```

Comment: I am getting the same result when I use either of those formats

Comment: The lines above shouldn't give that error. Either you haven't restarted the server after changing code, or you have a similar mistake somewhere else.